# Hibernate does not rollback trigger-related changes

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, triggers, transactions

I have an application with a MySQL database. This database has a table A and a trigger when a new row is inserted in this table.

Now, when I create new entity (associated to this table), and save it with `session.save(aEntity);` in a transaction, but when I execute the save, MySQL activates the trigger of table A and creates a new entry in some other table, but the row in table A is not saved until I call `transaction.commit()`.

I sometimes need do rollback `transaction.rollback()` but the trigger would create the new entry in other table and it won't be deleted.

How can i do it?

Comment: What MySQL table storage engine are you using? Please add the output of the following mysql command to your question: `show create table <TableName>`

Comment: The storage engine is InnoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [`save`](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/), Hibernate attached the entity to the Persistence Context and the database row will be added during flush. For MySQL, if you use the IDENTITY entity identifier generator, the insert will happen right away.

The trigger might add a record in some other table, but that's also part of the current database transaction (assuming you use InnoDB), so when you rollback the transaction, neither the TableA nor the other table will persist the pending changes.

So you should be fine.

### Update

> I'll try to explain. I have a table A and a table B. In MySQL, I have a
>   trigger that when a row is created in A, the trigger creates a row in B
>   with the same identifier of the row in A, (but without foreign key). In the
>   Hibernate Session, I created a transaction and make an entity of A and save it. The
>   trigger is activated and instantly creates an entry in B, but there
>   is still no entry in A because I didn't commit the transaction yet. After I do a
>   rollback, the table A is reverted but the row in B created by the trigger
>   is still there, referencing an entry in A that does not exist. B does not
>   have foreign keys and uses MyISAM.

This is not a typical DB setup and this is not really a Hibernate problem. You'd bump into this issue with plain JDBC too. The problem is that Table A uses the transaction-aware InnoDB storage engine while Table B works in auto-commit mode, due to being configured to use MyISAM.

Comment: Yes, I use InnoDB, but Is there any other way to activate the trigger only when I do `transaction.commit`?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Because sometimes I need do rollback, and the trigger generate a new row that I don't need because it creates an inconsistency. The new row generated by trigger, refer to table A, but as I did rollback, this entry don't exists.

Comment: But a rollback should revert the changes done by the trigger too.

Comment: I'll try to explain: I have a table A and a table B. In MySQL I have a trigger that when a row is created in A, trigger create a row in B with the identifier of row of A, (but without forgein key). In the session, I created a trasaction. I make a entity of A and save it. The trigger is activated, and instantly creates an entry in B, but there is still no entry in A because i don't commit yet. After I do rollback, and nothing creates in A but input B created by the trigger is created, referencing an entry in A that does not exist. B does not have forgein keys and uses MyISAM

Comment: In the first comment you said you are using InnoDB, now you say that B uses MyISAM. If you have different databases or schemas, then you need an XA/JTA transaction.

Comment: Yes, table A uses InnoDB and table B uses MyISAM

Comment: This is not a typical DB setup and this is not really a Hibernate problem. You'd bump into this issue with plain JDBC too. The problem is that Table A uses the transaction-aware InnoDB storage engine while Table B works in auto-commit mode, due to being configured to use MyISAM.

Comment: Thanks, there is te problem. I changed the engine of table B to InnoDB and now it's works.